# How to write correct sql request for my task

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the tables : `Users(id,name,...)`,`Knowledge(id,name,...)` and `Courses(id,name....)`.
Each user has multiple "knowledge"(user and knowledge link by type ManyToMany).
For example user "User1" have 2 knowledge "1" and "2".
Course also link with knowledge by type ManyToMany. But knowledge in this case is requirement.
For example Course "Course 1" require knowledge "1" and "2", and user may access for this course.
Course "Course 2" required knowledge "1" and "3", and user have not access for this course.

I want to write correct sql command, which returned all courses, which can get user.
I use PostgresSql.
Sorry for my terrible English.

I tried this sql command for join course and knowledge:

```
select c.id as "Course id", k.requiredknowledge_id  from course as c inner join courses_required_knowledges as k on k.course_id = c.id;
```

A similar command for join users and knowledge.

```
select u.id as "User id", k.knowledge_id from user_info as u inner join users_knowledge as k on k.userInfo_id = u.id where u.id = 1;
```

But i don't understand how to "combain" this commands for get result

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Also, tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: i think, maybe concat columns values (group by) and compare it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select c.id as "Course", array_agg(k.requiredknowledge_id) as "Requiried knoweldge" , array_agg(uk.knowledge_id) as "User Knowledge"
from course as c 
right join courses_required_knowledges as k on k.course_id = c.id 
right join users_knowledge as uk on uk.userInfo_id = 1
group by c.id 
having array_agg(k.requiredknowledge_id) <@ array_agg(uk.knowledge_id);
```

This example work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like this.

First let's create some test data:

```
create table course (id int primary key, name varchar(20));
insert into course (id, name) values
(1,'cooking'),
(2,'super hero'),
(3,'otaku');

create table knowledge (id int primary key, name varchar(30));
insert into knowledge (id, name) values
(4,'boil egg'),
(5,'toast bread'),
(6,'maintain secret identity'),
(7,'read');

create table courses_required_knowledges (id int primary key, course_id int, requiredknowledge_id int);
insert into courses_required_knowledges (id, course_id, requiredknowledge_id) values
(8,1,4),
(9,1,5),
(10,2,6),
(11,3,7);

create table user_info (id int primary key, name varchar(20));
insert into user_info (id, name) values
(12,'John Doe'),
(13,'Konata'),
(14,'Mega Mindy');

create table users_knowledge (id serial primary key, userInfo_id int, knowledge_id int);
insert into users_knowledge (userInfo_id, knowledge_id) values
(12,4),
(12,7),
(12,5),
(13,7),
(14,6),
(14,7),
(14,5);
```

The query below joins them on the correspondent fields.
With the user table cross joined (all to all) to the required courses.

```
select 
-- course.id as course_id,
-- coursereq.requiredknowledge_id,
-- user_info.id as user_id,
course.name as course,
reqknow.name as required_knowledge,
user_info.name as username,
(case when users_knowledge.id is null then 'N' else 'Y' end) as user_meets_requirement
from courses_required_knowledges as coursereq
full outer join user_info on (1=1)
left join users_knowledge
   on (user_info.id = users_knowledge.userInfo_id and
       coursereq.requiredknowledge_id = users_knowledge.knowledge_id)
left join knowledge as reqknow
   on (coursereq.requiredknowledge_id = reqknow.id)
-- left join knowledge as usrknow
--   on (users_knowledge.knowledge_id = usrknow.id)
left join course
   on (coursereq.course_id = course.id)
where users_knowledge.id is null
order by
course.name, reqknow.name, user_info.name;
```

Which will give the requirements missed by the users to enroll in a course.

Result:

```
course      required_knowledge        username    user_meets_requirement

cooking     boil egg                  Konata      N
cooking     boil egg                  Mega Mindy  N
cooking     toast bread               Konata      N
super hero  maintain secret identity  John Doe    N
super hero  maintain secret identity  Konata      N
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i did big mistake in question tables link by ManyToMany. I will edit my question

Comment: I had some fun with the names.